# Find k vertices in a tree to cover the maximum number of edges

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, greedy

My idea is a greedy one.

I maintain E[i] as the number of edges connected with vertex i.

```
Repeat following k times:

    Every time I extract largest E[k] and add vertex k to the result set, and I decrease E[t] by 1 for every vertex t adjacent to k.

    Set E[k] = 0;
```

However, I don't know my idea is right or not.. And I don't know how to prove it.

If not, what is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you ask these type of questions at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with sudomakeinstall2.  But this problem sounds NP hard, which means a greedy approach won't work.

Comment: Whoops... But actually the question require me to solve it in O(k^2*n) time.. Thank you for your information! I yesterday post this question on Mathematics and no one replies either..

Comment: @Tipton I think this approach is not correct. what happen when after extract K nodes none of those are connected with any other on this subgraph? exactly, you have found a subgraph without edges.

Answer (score 0):

This greedy approach is **not correct**.

Let's consider that you are asked to compute the maximum number of edges that
4 nodes can cover (k = 4) in the graph below:

[image]

Your algorithm would select **Node 1** and then pick **3 nodes out of {2,3,4,5}**.

With this selection you will cover **7 edges**, when instead you could pick nodes 2,3,4 and 5 and cover all 8 edges!